# Getting 400 error while uploading the image using the WCF services and Base64Request

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, json

I am trying to upload the image using the webservices and Base64string.

But each time I am trying to upload the image it gives me BAD REQUEST (400) Error.

I have googled much about this, it says error is due to the large amount of data is been passed in request.

So I tried to increase the data length from web.config, but adding this.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!-- buffer: 64KB; max size: 64MB -->
        <binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But still it gives me the error.

here is my function.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
string AddAlbum(string imgstring)
```

And I am calling this function as follows :-

```
public string PostRemoteJSON(string strurl, string param)
        {
            try
            {
                strurl = "http://mydomain.com/EventService.svc/AddAlbum";
                param = "{\"imgstring\":\"BASE64STRINGCONTENT\"}";

            WebRequest myWebRequest;
            Stream myRequestStream;
            StreamWriter myStreamWriter;
            WebResponse myWebResponse;
            myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strurl);

            myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            myWebRequest.Timeout = 1000000;
            myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            myWebRequest.ContentLength = param.Length;
            myRequestStream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            myStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(myRequestStream);

            myRequestStream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

            myStreamWriter.Write(param);
            myStreamWriter.Flush();
            myStreamWriter.Close();
            myRequestStream.Close();

            myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
            return reader.ReadToEnd();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were facing the same issue in [our project](http://xenta.net). I assume you were having this issue while debugging your app. It seems like DevServer doesn't support streamed bindings. If you have already tried to increase quotas and buffers, but it didn't solve the issue, try to deploy your app in IIS, for us it all works fine in IIS environment.

Comment: I am not debugging the project, actually i have uploaded it and test using the other project.

Comment: Ok. Then you will need to check you bindings configuration. Check readerQuotas and etc. Check these two links: http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11155#112366 and http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11155#165176.This our configuration for server and client sides. Take a look at basicHttpBinding streamed bindings.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting maxBufferSize, maxArrayLength and maxReceiveMessageSize all to a value double (for testing) the size of your maximum request payload. Setting it exactly to 64k does not account for serialization and protocol overhead and is too small.